# Why doesn't void take a void value in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, types

I'm curious why C++ does not define void via :

```
typedef struct { } void;
```

I.e. what is the value in a type that cannot be instantiated, even if that installation must produce no code?

If we use `gcc -O3 -S`, then both the following produce identical assembler :

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

and

```
template <class T> T f(T a) { }
typedef struct { } moo;
int main() { moo a; f(a); return 0; }
```

This makes perfect sense.  A `struct { }` simply takes an empty value, easy enough to optimize away.  In fact, the strange part is that they produce different code without the `-O3`.

You cannot however pull this same trick with simply `typedef void moo` because void cannot assume any value, not even an empty one.  Does this distinction have any utility?

There are various other strongly typed languages like Haskell, and presumably the MLs, that have a value for their void type, but offer no valueless types overtly, although some posses native pointer types, which act like `void *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the rationale for `void` being unable to be instantiated coming from the C roots of C++. In the old gory days, type safety wasn't that big a deal and `void*`s were constantly passed around. However, you could always be looking at code that does not literally say `void*` (due to `typedef`s, macros, and in C++, templates) but still means it.

It is a tiny bit of safety if you cannot dereference a `void*` but have to cast it to a pointer to a proper type, first. Whether you accomplish that by using an incomplete type as [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9969529/430766) suggests, or if you use the built-in `void` type doesn't matter. You're protected from incorrectly *guessing* that you are dealing with a type, which you are not.

Yes, `void` introduces annoying special cases, especially when designing templates. But it's a good thing (i.e. intentional) that the compiler doesn't silently accept attempts to instantiate `void`.

Comment: I agree with mostly everything, except the last paragraph. The annoying special cases it introduces when dealing with templates are intentional? What for? To annoy programmers?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Well, not intentional that it annoys us, but intentional in the sense that your library should be able to deal with types it *cannot instantiate*, `void` being the most prominent example. For instance, if you wrote a type-safe `memcpy` template that essentially does this: `*to = *from`. Then plugging in `void` *should* make the complier call you names, not silently accept it, simply because copying the OPs dummy value for `void` wouldn't have been what you had in mind!

Comment: I'll grant this historical viewpoint makes sense.  If templates don't exist, then you don't consider specializing type variables to types which cannot contain data.  Instead you worry about people doing silly things with values that cannot exist.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I rephrased the wording of that paragraph.

Comment: @JeffBurdges: There are approaches where people tried to emulate templates in C by including non-guarded header files that relied on external `typedef`s. It's the same problem, just an order of magnitude uglier to implement and maintain (plus, specialising is harder).

Comment: The ISO committee actually did quite a bit of work to make `void` work better in templates. E.g. in `template <class T> T bar()`, a `return foo();` statement is legal even if `T==void`. It's a special case for compilers, not for users.

Answer (score 3):

Because that wouldn't make `void` an incomplete type, now would it?

Try your example code again with:

```
struct x; // incomplete
typedef x moo;
```

Comment: Is `moo` an incomplete type in my example?  It works fine the very few places I've used it.

Comment: @Jeff: No, your `moo` is a complete type.  Mine is incomplete.  `void` is an incomplete type that can never be completed.

Comment: What would you say is the advantage of `void` being an incomplete type?

Comment: Exactly R.M.F., my question could be rephrased as : Why *should* `void` be an incomplete type?

Comment: @R: So that it can't be used in contexts which require a complete type (such as `sizeof`)?  If `void` didn't have this special status of permanently-incomplete type, how would you define a function without a return value (as opposed to one returning an instance of `void`)?

Comment: From a functional point of view, there is no such thing as a function without a return value, only functions that return no _information_. If there exists only one instance of `void`, then no information is returned.

Comment: I think I can see the point in `sizeof(void)` not being allowed. Regarding returns, there would be no difference between the two kinds of functions you mentioned.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: If C++ was a truly functional language, we'd just use `tuple<>` (a tuple with 0 members). But C++ is an extension to C, historically. The remark would make more sense in Java, but even they chose C's model ("`java.lang.Void` is an uninstantiable placeholder class")

Comment: @MSalters: It's not even that C++ is an extension to C; it's *not* a functional language. It can be used that way, especially if you whip out template metaprogramming. But on the whole, it was never intended to be a purely functional language.

Comment: Functional vs. imperative is irrelevent execpt that modern functional language use Hindley-Milner type inference, which means rejecting type casting.  `void` is only useful if you allow implicit typecasting.  An imperative language that rejected implicit type casting in favor of type inference and type safety would also reject `void` in favor of `struct { }`, `tuple<>`, unit, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

> Why *should* `void` be an incomplete type?

There are many reasons.

The simplest is this: `moo FuncName(...)` must still return something. Whether it is a neutral value, whether it is the "not a value value", or whatever; it still must say `return value;`, where `value` is some actual value. It must say `return moo();`.

Why write a function that technically returns something, when it isn't actually returning something? The compiler can't optimize the return out, because it's returning a value of a complete type. The caller might actually use it.

C++ isn't all templates, you know. The compiler doesn't necessarily have the knowledge to throw everything away. It often has to perform in-function optimizations that have no knowledge of the external use of that code.

`void` in this case means "I don't return anything." There is a fundamental difference between that and "I return a meaningless value." It is legal to do this:

```
moo FuncName(...) { return moo(); }

moo x = FuncName(...);
```

This is at best misleading. A cursory scan suggests that a value is being returned and stored. The identifier `x` now has a value and can be used for something.

Whereas this:

```
void FuncName(...) {}

void x = FuncName(...);
```

is a compiler error. So is this:

```
void FuncName(...) {}

moo x = FuncName(...);
```

It's clear what's going on: `FuncName` has no return value.

Even if you were designing C++ from scratch, with no hold-overs from C, you would *still* need some keyword to indicate the difference between a function that returns a value and one that does not.

Furthermore, `void*` is special in part because `void` is not a complete type. Because the standard mandates that it isn't a complete type, the concept of a `void*` can mean "pointer to untyped memory." This has specialized casting semantics. Pointers to typed memory can be implicitly cast to untyped memory. Pointers to untyped memory can be explicitly cast back to the typed pointer that it used to be.

If you used `moo*` instead, then the semantics get weird. You have a pointer to *typed* memory. Currently, C++ defines casting between unrelated typed pointers (except for certain special cases) to be undefined behavior. Now the standard has to add another exception for the `moo` type. It has to say what happens when you do this:

```
moo *m = new moo;
*moo;
```

With `void`, this is a compiler error. What is it with `moo`? It's still useless and meaningless, but the compiler has to allow it.

To be honest, I would say that the better question would be "Why should `void` be a *complete* type?"

Comment: There are many situations where you want to specialize the parameter of a polymorphic type to nothing because doing so makes sense logically, makes the code more readable, improves code reuse, etc.  I'm not surprised you cannot cast from a `void` to a `moo`, but this would never arise in practice.

Comment: To add a few extra bonuses: `throw moo()`, `moo[5]` - all things that don't work with `void` _because_ it's incomplete.

Comment: @JeffBurdges: Then you can create your own empty "nothing" class and do what you need.

Comment: I asked because that unit (nothing) type is elementary in languages with vastly more carefully thought out type systems than C++, the compelling answer was "there is no good reason except the historical convenience in the evolution of C", which makes good sense.  I.e. people actually worry about casting to `void` when they aren't hardly using type safety in the first place.  `void` presumably doesn't make any sense in a type safe world.

Comment: @JeffBurdges: Compelling to you perhaps; not necessarily to others. You've not provided a compelling reason (to me) to actually have such a construct built into the language.

Comment: `struct { }` permits compile time polymorphism that results in potentially vastly more efficient code.  The return type `void`  is certainly covered by `struct { }`.  `void *` is useful, but perhaps `struct { } *` could behave that way as well.  I'd need to think more carefully about it.

Comment: @JeffBurdges: Polymorphism of *what*? What are you talking about?